# Analyze in Excel from Power BI not showing hierarchies

Tags: powerbi

I am using Snowflake as my backend database and created & published a dataset in Power BI with direct query. As a next step I am trying to analyze the data (to get Pivot experience) in excel.

I am observing the hierarchies I have created are not showing up in excel, though those are showing when accessing through PBI Service.

Answer (score 1):

DirectQuery comes with a [slew of limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about) compared to imported datasets. The only hierarchy-specific limitation included in the official documentation is that Auto date-time hierarchies are not created for DQ datasets. However, this documentation is about direct limitations and doesn't specifically cover limitations that might only be applied to XMLA connections, which your connection from Excel is.

A workaround is to just use computed columns with the hierarchy values and name them like Category01, Category02, Category03 and do the nesting yourself. Users often have use cases that involve using hierarchies out of order (like grouping by Category03 THEN by Category01) and so consider it a feature rather than a flaw.

Comment: Microsoft suggesting to use "Power BI + Analyze in Excel" feature to modernize existing SSAS cube. But it is very surprised, some important features are not available yet. It is always very difficult to convince user to access the data in a different way than they are doing now. If I have 10 dimensions and total of 30 hierarchies, then think, how many combinations I have to create as per your suggestion.

Comment: In that case, I would certainly keep trying to make it work. I haven't had such a scenario, and I do understand how difficult it is to get a large user base to change their habits. If you open an empty PBIX and connect to your published model as a Power BI Dataset, can you see the hierarchies there? This step will tell you whether the issue is on the XMLA endpoint or Excel specifically.